# How do I use a while-loop correctly to capitalize text fields content until an empty field is found?

Tags: javascript, html, while-loop

I need to create a function that is triggered by a press of a button that allows me to create every character in multiple text fields capitalized until the code reads a text field without any content in it. I need to use a while-loop in my function in order to perform the task.

To be more specific, I need the function to change the text of the fields in order from top to bottom so that the act of changing the text to uppercase can stop when there is nothing in the field.

I thought my code would work but apparently, it does not.

I have a button that makes the text fields content turn into uppercase, but I need the second button to perform the job described above.

```js
var theInputedText;

function buttonClicked() {
  for (var textField = 0; textField <= 9; textField++) {
    document.textInput.elements[textField].value =
      document.textInput.elements[textField].value.toUpperCase();

  }
}

function secondButtonClicked() {
  var textLength = document.textInput.elements[0].value.length;
  var initialTextField = 0;
  var textFields = 0;

  while (document.textInput.elements[textFields].value != null)
    document.textInput.elements[textFields].value =
    document.textInput.elements[textFields].value.toUpperCase();
  textFields++;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <form name="textInput">
    <input type="text"><br>
    <input type="text"><br>
    <input type="text"><br>
    <input type="text"><br>
    <input type="text"><br>
    <input type="text"><br>
    <input type="text"><br>
    <input type="text"><br>
    <input type="text"><br>
    <input type="text"><br><br>
    <input type="button" Value="Change First Letter to Uppercase" onclick=buttonClicked()>
    <input type="button" Value="Change all Letters to Uppercase" onclick=secondButtonClicked()>
  </form>
</body>
```

When a user types into the text fields, say the first 5 skips 6 and fills the rest, then presses the second button. The first 5 fields should turn into uppercase letters while the next 5 stay as they were typed.

The actual result is that it just does not work and I don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

Change the condition inside while from

```
document.textInput.elements[textFields].value != null
```

to

```
document.textInput.elements[textFields].value
```

Comment: Will that make the while-loop stop running when there is no text in the field and prevent it from changing any further text?

Comment: yes it will stop the while loop for the first empty field

Answer (score 0):

```
Suppose You use a count as a variable which increments on every iteration and is initialised as 0.
Then the condition for while will be :

function secondButtonClicked() {
  var textLength = document.textInput.elements[0].value.length;
  var initialTextField = 0;
  var textFields = 0;
  var count = 0;

  while (count < textLength)
    document.textInput.elements[textFields].value =
    document.textInput.elements[textFields].value.toUpperCase();
  count++;
}
```

Comment: How does this fulfill the needs to detect when a field is empty when the second button is pressed. And the textFields variable needs to be changed so it can be text fields 0-9.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is missing something, I got this solution:

```js
function buttonClicked() {
  // this variable will handle the counter of textfields
  var textFields = 0;
  
  // the next loop will execute forever, unless textField.value is void or there is no more text fields
  while (true) {
    if (!document.textInput.elements[textFields] || !document.textInput.elements[textFields].value) {
    // here we break the loop, it means a void textField or there is no textField to proccess
    break;
    }
    
    // We need to trim out blank spaces, this way we ensure toUpperCase() method works
    document.textInput.elements[textFields].value = document.textInput.elements[textFields].value.trim();
    
    // We capitalize the first character of the string and save it on a variable called 'capitalized'
    var capitalized = document.textInput.elements[textFields].value.substring(0,1).toUpperCase();
    
    var unCapitalized = '';

    if (document.textInput.elements[textFields].value.length > 1) {
      // We save the rest of the string in a variable called 'unCapitalized' only if there is enough characters on it
      unCapitalized = document.textInput.elements[textFields].value.substring(1);
    }

    // Now we set the value of textField with the desired result
    document.textInput.elements[textFields].value = capitalized.concat(unCapitalized);
    
    // Don't forget to increment our counter;
    textFields++;
  } // End while loop
} // End function buttonClicked()


// The next function is basically the same as above
// except that we capitalize all the characters on the string
function secondButtonClicked() {
  // start our counter
  var textFields = 0;
  
  // this loop runs until one of 2 conditions listed above are satisfied
  while (true) {
    if (!document.textInput.elements[textFields] || !document.textInput.elements[textFields].value) {
      break;
    }
    
    // Don't forget to trim out the blank spaces
    document.textInput.elements[textFields].value = document.textInput.elements[textFields].value.trim();
    
    // here we just capitalize the whole string
    document.textInput.elements[textFields].value = document.textInput.elements[textFields].value.toUpperCase();
    
    // Again, don't forget to increment the counter
    textFields++;
  } // End while loop
} // End function secondButtonClicked()
```

```html
<body>
  <form name="textInput">
    <input type="text"><br>
    <input type="text"><br>
    <input type="text"><br>
    <input type="text"><br>
    <input type="text"><br>
    <input type="text"><br>
    <input type="text"><br>
    <input type="text"><br>
    <input type="text"><br>
    <input type="text"><br><br>
    <button type="button" onclick=buttonClicked()>Change First Letter to Uppercase</button>
    <button type="button" onclick=secondButtonClicked()>Change all Letters to Uppercase</button>
  </form>
</body>
```

I've changed the HTML either, in your code you got `<input type="button"...>` so, when you click on it, the `value` of that `input` was proccessed as well.

The solution is to use a `button` html tag.

Hope this works for you.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood your question or get confused about the names of the Buttons. In any case, I think my algorithm works for your need.